# numberformat exception for input string :"1201" in sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am getting following error while exporting data from HDFS to MySQL using sqoop. I created the table employee with `bigint` and `varchar`.

```
17/01/04 19:30:14 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/01/04 19:30:14 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/01/04 19:30:15 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/01/04 19:30:15 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/01/04 19:30:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `employee` AS t LIMIT 1
17/01/04 19:30:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `employee` AS t LIMIT 1
17/01/04 19:30:16 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /home/adithyan/hadoop_dir/hadoop-1.2.1
Note: /tmp/sqoop-adithyan/compile/0555b3b23ccf665b309ee88adde7936e/employee.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/01/04 19:30:21 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-adithyan/compile/0555b3b23ccf665b309ee88adde7936e/employee.jar
17/01/04 19:30:21 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of employee
17/01/04 19:30:28 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/01/04 19:30:28 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
17/01/04 19:30:29 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
17/01/04 19:30:29 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
17/01/04 19:30:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201701041906_0005
17/01/04 19:30:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/01/04 19:31:21 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201701041906_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '1201'
    at employee.__loadFromFields(employee.java:378)
    at employee.parse(employee.java:306)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1201"
    at
```

Following is the data in HDFS which I am trying to export using sqoop

```
1201, gopal,     manager, 50000, TP
1202, manisha,   preader, 50000, TP
1203, kalil,     php dev, 30000, AC
1204, prasanth,  php dev, 30000, AC
1205, kranthi,   admin,   20000, TP
1206, satish p,  grp des, 20000, GR
```

I am using `mysql-5.1.28.jar`, `hadoop-1.2.8`.

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132409/discussion-on-question-by-adithyan-p-numberformat-exception-for-input-string).